# Pip not working

Tags: python, python3, pip

I am currently trying to install some packages via pip, for some Python development, and I keep coming to these errors. I already tried to disable the firewall, but the error persists. Any idea of what might be causing this?

```
Collecting matplotlib
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/matplotlib/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for matplotlib
```

Comment: It seems to be a network issue. Is your network ok!  Please post your pip command too.

Comment: The pip command that I used was: 'python3 -m pip install matplotlib'.
How could I check my network, to trace the problem?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read this usually happens when you're behind a proxy, but in my case it happened because apparently my ISP screwed up (source below). So, if you're a MEO ISP client (Portugal) you may have to disable ipv6.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6'
```

Source: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5374